# How to factor the polynomial $x^4-x^2-2x-1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

By taking advantage of a computer algebra system, I found out that

$$x^4 - x^2 - 2x - 1 = (x^2 + x + 1)(x^2 - x - 1)$$

However, I don't know a straightforward way to solve this by hand. This was in a high-schooler's homework set, so I am assuming it can be solved using elementary methods.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Recognize the square:

$$x^4-(x^2+2x+1)=x^4-(x+1)^2$$

now apply the "difference-of-squares" rule and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

Upon looking at this expression I *immediately* noticed that the $-x^2-2x-1$ could be simplified to $-(x+1)^2$. That is how you should be later on. For example, when you see $4x^2-4x+1$, you should right away notice that it equals $(2x-1)^2$
$$x^4-x^2-2x-1=x^4-(x+1)^2$$
$$=\left(x^2\right)^2-(x+1)^2$$
$$=(x^2+x+1)(x^2-(x+1)$$
$$=(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x-1)$$
$$\displaystyle \color{green}{\boxed{\therefore x^4-x^2-2x-1=(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x-1)}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if there's a real root of this polynomial then there's a second real root (why?) and if there's a complex root non real $z$  then $\overline z$ is also a root of the polynomial (also why?), in the two cases there's a quadratic polynomial with real coefficients divides the given polynomial hence we can factorize it on this form:

$$x^4 - x^2 - 2x - 1=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx +d)$$
Can you identify the coefficients $a,b,c$ and $d$?